# Add columns of frequency counts for each level of factor level and reshape dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like so:

```
 df<- data.frame(region = c("1","1","1","1","1","2","2"),
            loc = c("104","104","104","105","105","106","107"), 
            plntsp = c("A","A", "B", "C", "C", "E", "F"), 
            lepsp = c("Z","Z", "Y", "W", "X", "T", "T"))
```

And I want to:
1)  find the frequencies of `plntsp` and `lepsp` for each `region` and `loc` subset. 
2)make it a long dataframe where  the `plantsp` and `lepsp` columns are collapsed into one column titled `sp`. And the new count columns are collapsed into one count column called `freq`.

```
output<- data.frame(region = c("1","1","1","1","2","1","1","1","2","2","2"),
loc = c("104","104","105","106","107","104","104","105","105","106","107"), 
sp = c("A","B", "C", "E", "F", "Z", "Y","W", "X", "T", "T"), 
freq = c("2","1", "2", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"))
```

I have tried:

```
df<- 
group_by(region,loc) %>%
summarise(freq1= length(unique(plantsp), freq2= length(unique(lepsp))
mutate(sp= df$plantsp &df$lepsp, freq= df$freq1 &df$freq2)
```

Comment: Do the collapse to long-form first, then group it back up by `region/loc/newspcolumn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aggregate` would be one option

```
rbind(aggregate(list(freq = seq_along(df$plntsp)),
                by = list(region = df$region,loc = df$loc, sp = df$plntsp),
                FUN = length),
      aggregate(list(freq = seq_along(df$plntsp)),
                by = list(region = df$region, loc = df$loc, sp = df$lepsp),
                FUN = length))
#   region loc sp freq
#1       1 104  A    2
#2       1 104  B    1
#3       1 105  C    2
#4       2 106  E    1
#5       2 107  F    1
#6       2 106  T    1
#7       2 107  T    1
#8       1 105  W    1
#9       1 105  X    1
#10      1 104  Y    1
#11      1 104  Z    2
```

Or use `melt` of `reshape2` before using `aggregate`

```
library(reshape2)
opt = melt(data = df, id.vars = c("region", "loc"))
#Warning message:
#attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped 
aggregate(list(freq=opt$value), opt[c("region","loc","value")], FUN = length)
#   region loc value freq
#1       1 104     A    2
#2       1 104     B    1
#3       1 105     C    2
#4       2 106     E    1
#5       2 107     F    1
#6       2 106     T    1
#7       2 107     T    1
#8       1 105     W    1
#9       1 105     X    1
#10      1 104     Y    1
#11      1 104     Z    2
```

Comment: Your `aggregate`s could be made a lot shorter if you just select the columns of `opt`/`df` for the `by=` argument - `aggregate(list(freq=opt$value), opt[c("region","loc","value")], FUN = length)` for example

Comment: It's not really important for the solution in my eyes but the OP explicitely requested how the columns should be named. Would you mind to amend your solution accordingly, just for comparison with other answers, please?

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  gather(key, sp, plntsp, lepsp) %>%
  group_by(region, loc, sp) %>%
  count(.) %>%
  rename(x=n)

   region    loc    sp     x
 1      1    104     A     2
 2      1    104     B     1
 3      1    104     Y     1
 4      1    104     Z     2
 5      1    105     C     2
 6      1    105     W     1
 7      1    105     X     1
 8      2    106     E     1
 9      2    106     T     1
10      2    107     F     1
11      2    107     T     1
```

Comment: It's not really important for the solution in my eyes but the OP explicitely requested how the columns should be named. Would you mind to amend your solution accordingly, just for comparison with other answers, please?

Answer (score 0):

This `data.table` solution follows [the advice from thelatemail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/496803/thelatemail) to reshape to long format first and then to count appearances.

The `melt()` function to reshape data from wide to long format is available from two packages: `reshape2` and `data.table`. I prefer the latter for performance reasons and the concise syntax:

```
library(data.table)
id_vars = c("region", "loc")
melt(setDT(df), id.vars = id_vars, value.name = "sp")[, .(freq = .N), c(id_vars, "sp")]
```

> ```
>     region loc sp freq
>  1:      1 104  A    2
>  2:      1 104  B    1
>  3:      1 105  C    2
>  4:      2 106  E    1
>  5:      2 107  F    1
>  6:      1 104  Z    2
>  7:      1 104  Y    1
>  8:      1 105  W    1
>  9:      1 105  X    1
> 10:      2 106  T    1
> 11:      2 107  T    1
> ```

Note that the columns have been renamed as requested by the OP. For comparison with the other answers posted the far, the code is even more condensed without renaming the columns:

```
melt(setDT(df), id.vars = id_vars)[, .N, c(id_vars, "value")]
```